# Get HTML file name that sent the form data

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using ASP classic to get strings from a form on an HTML file using

```
Request.Form("Name")
```

I can add a fake input that will hold the html file's name for me like so:

```
 <input name="Page" type="hidden" value="filename.htm">
```

And then in the ASP file use

```
Request.Form("Page")
```

But I think there must be a smarter way for the ASP code to get the HTML filename.

Am I right? If so, how is it done?

**As an alternative, maybe there is a way to get the HTML filename into the HTML itself with JavaScript?
so that I'll be able to change the value of the input to the filename of the HTML holding it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understand right, you want to get the http referer. According [this](http://www.aspheute.com/artikel/20020121.htm) *german* website you looked for `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`.

**Note:** keep in mind that a user can disable the option in his browser sending the referer information. In this case, you current way is maybe the better one...

Comment: Depending on browser preferences might be a problem.
I'll edit my question and add another optional solution.

Comment: @Zephram I don't know how you store the filename into your hidden field. If you use javascript for that and the user blocks all js, what will you do?